# Is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.SelectToken thread safe?

Tags: c#, json.net

In a multithreaded console program, I use JObject and JArray to store data information. One thread gets object like this:

```
string xpath = "$.foo[?(@.id == '{id}')]";
JToken tok = fooObj.SelectToken(xpath);
... ...
```

In other threads, the JObject may be read and modified at the same time.

The program runs well almost all the time but in rare cases, it crashed at the call of SelectToken. Here is the log information copied from System Event Viewer.

```
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(System.ExceptionResource) System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[[System.__Canon,mscorlib,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNextRare()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.QueryFilter+<ExecuteFilter>d__4.MoveNext()
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.SelectToken(System.String, Boolean)
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.SelectToken(System.String)
<My code call to SelectToken>
... ...
```

It is said that Json.NET is thread safe on its homepage, but I'm not sure if it means I can access a JObject or JArray anywhere without any synchronization.

So, my question is, what should I do to prevent the exception caused by SelectToken(or maybe other call I haven't met yet)?

Add lock everywhere a JObject is accessed in all threads?

Or, the error was caused by other reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the question? Why would you use the *same* JObject from different threads? They *aren't* meant to store data, they are used to parse or serialize data to JSON and back. The XPath expression you used is essentially LINQ's `First(x=>x.ID=id)` or `Single(...)` without offering *any* benefits. It would actually be faster to use a `Dictionary<int,Foo>` to index and access Foo objects by ID. A `ConcurrentDictionary` would allow concurrent modifications, assuming that was needed

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've already realize that it not proper to use JObject as in memory data structure. But as a technical question, I want to know why it crashed and what does 'thread safe' mean said by Newtonsoft.

Comment: Said *where*, refering to which classes? Parsing is thread safe. You didn't use the parsing methods though.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very clear, I have no problem with parsing or serializing, the question is that I reserved JObject and JArray object loaded from json file for convenience because I needn't to convert them to C# container such as Dictionary or List.

Comment: Newtonsoft said that Json.NET is thread safe, is this means that I can use JObject just like ConcurrentDictionary? I'm afraid not, but I don't know what is the standard usage.

Comment: Newtonsoft has said that `JsonSerializer` is thread safe, see [Is the Json.NET JsonSerializer threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189439).  Individual `JObject` or `JArray` objects are not thread-safe when modified as you have seen.

Comment: [`JPropertyKeyedCollection`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JPropertyKeyedCollection.cs), for instance, contains an underlying `Dictionary<string, JToken>? _dictionary` which is only thread-safe for multiple readers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety