# Should I create a new JsonSerializer object for every request i need to deserialize?

Tags: c#, json.net

I know that httpclient should be reused, but i'm curious if the same rules apply to the other objects used in this method specifically the JsonSerializer object when deserializing.

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string actionName, object postData)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(actionName));
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Content = new StringContent(postData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var newClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        newClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenModel.Token);

        var result = await newClient.PostAsync(request.RequestUri, request.Content);

        using (var streamReader = BuildNonClosingStreamReader(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            JsonSerializer s = new JsonSerializer();
            return s.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [Is the Json.NET JsonSerializer threadsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189439), `JsonSerializer` is thread-safe, however it is mutable (it has many settings that can be modified) and there have been bugs regarding thread safety in the past (e.g. [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1452)) so I don't really recommend sharing a single instance between threads.  Beyond that, this question looks primarily opinion based.

Comment: For newtonsoft it does not appear that JsonConvert deserializes streams the same way as JsonSerializer.

Comment: `JsonConvert` eventually calls [`JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(JsonSerializerSettings)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CreateDefault_1.htm) which takes the global serializer settings into account.  There's also a subtle difference with the default value for [`CheckAdditionalContent`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_CheckAdditionalContent.htm) where `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` doesn't check for additional content unless explicitly told do, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37173878/3744182]).

Comment: Those are the differences of which I am aware.  But your question was whether to create a `JsonSerializer` every time, not whether to deserialize from a stream vs from a string.